# How do I downgrade .net from 4.5.2 to 4.5

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to switch the Target Framework on one of my projects from 4.5.2 to 4.5 (the computers we're installing on only have .net 4.5 and IT won't let us update to 4.5.2)

I'm using Visual Studio 2015

I've switched the Target Framework in Properties -> Application -> Target Framework to ".NET Framework 4.5" This changed my csproj file to this

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>

...

<BootstrapperPackage Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5">
  <Visible>False</Visible>
  <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 %28x86 and x64%29</ProductName>
  <Install>true</Install>
</BootstrapperPackage>
```

I've updated app.config to this

```
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
</startup>
```

I also changed my packages config file to update Newtonsoft.Json targetFramework

```
<packages>
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="7.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

After I made these changes and Published my project. During the setup, when it is installing the components, it is still trying to download and install .NET 4.5.2

Is there another reference somewhere. Or is there a something else I need to do to get the framework to switch?

Comment: are you sure that you have downgraded for ALL projects in the solution? You mention publishing - what does the publishing profile look like? How are you doing the publishing? is it a web publish? installshield? Right click > publish?

Comment: I only have one project in this solution. I use the publish wizard in Visual Studio and have it setup to check for updates from a url. That part seems to be working, as my test machine is picking up the new versions.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5 is automatically updated to 4.5.2 by Windows Update.  Never any need to help.  IT staff that blocks WU intentionally are doing something very, very, very wrong.  4.5 RTM had very serious bugs, everybody forgot about them because Microsoft patched it quickly.  Patches delivered through WU.  And a litany of critical security problem fixes, too many to count.  Delivered through WU, not retro-actively applied to older runtime versions.  Blocking them is, well, stoopid.  Never target 4.5.1 or 4.5.2 in a project, there's no point.

Comment: It's a hospital IT department, which does things extremely slowly. They are still on IE8 and have a 2 year plan to upgrade to IE10. We have a request to update .NET which should happen in the next couple of weeks, But we need to software to work in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you changed the target framework for debug mode (application properties). Do it for release mode as well.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was simple, I was not updating the setup.exe file that I was using to install the app from.